# How to conditionally update the elasticsearch document?

Tags: elasticsearch

Using update query for document as follows:

```
/<indexname>/_update/<id>
{
    doc: {
        /// the doc here
    }
}
```

Is there a way, I can put condition like created_at field in the existing doc is less than created_at we are passing?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) api.

e.g.

```
POST <index>/_update_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "range": {
      "created_at": {
         "lte": "2019-01-10"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but how do I update in this a particular documentId? Where would I give the new document?